# Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit using Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

Im getting this error code.

```
(22): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
```

With this code.

```
number2     DWORD   ? ; Fahrenheit temp
prompt1     BYTE    "Enter the temp", 0
string      BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLbl   BYTE    "The sum is", 0
result      BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input prompt1, string, 40 ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string ; convert to integer
        mov     prompt1, eax ; store in memory

        imul    eax, 5 ; multiply f times 9
        add     eax, 2 ; rounding
        mov     ebx, 9 ; divisor
        cdq ; change the double to a quad for divison
        idiv    ebx ; mutiply f * 9/5
        sub     eax, 32 ; then subtract by 32
        mov     number2, eax
        output  resultLbl, number2 
    
        mov     eax, 0
        ret

_MainProc ENDP
END ; end of source code
```

what could I do this fix this please help. I'm not sure if its my registers or my syntax any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mov     prompt1, eax`  overwrites `prompt1`, presumably not what you wanted. This causes error A2022, but it's otherwise harmless. I don't know how `output  resultLbl, number2` works but you should convert the result `number2` from binary to ASCII string first and then print this string.

Answer (score -1):

The correct formula is `(C*9)/5 + 32`.

I would write this way (Intel syntax):

```
.globl celsius_to_fahrenheit
celsius_to_fahrenheit:
        imul eax, edi, 9
        mov  ecx,5
        cdq
        idiv ecx
        add  eax, 32
        ret
```

Correctly working example: https://godbolt.org/z/a98TKj1G5

Comment: This exact code is for the x86-64 System V calling convention, not 32-bit Windows, and using the GAS directive `.globl` not MASM.  But fortunately the syntax for the actual math instructions is the same so it should be easy to adapt.  Still not helpful to the OP in getting their program to build, since they're writing the I/O parts in asm as well, and that's where their current roadblock is.

Comment: (Question titles unfortunately often describe the overall goal of the program, not the actual problem with it.  In this case where a better title would be "instruction operands must be the same size error when trying to store an integer over some string data" because that's what the question body is about.  But yeah, the next bug they'd run into after removing that useless `mov` store is that their output function probably just outputs bytes, not doing int->ASCII-string for you, so fixing all the bugs requires a much longer answer.)

Comment: Sorry just trying to help as there are no other answers. If you want you can remove it. Thanks